# Show Due dates for linked issues in Jira

Tags: jira, confluence, jql

I want to make a Confluence page which tracks my jira tickets and the issues that are linked to those tickets.
Till now I have done this:

```
project= ABC AND "Epic Link"= 'Epic1' AND status != 'closed'
```

I want to create a table that has Jira- key, summary, tasks, due date, status and linked issues.

I want to make sure that I show linked issues that are only linked to the current epic (that is Epic1) and also show the due dates of these issues.

I have tired doing this:-

```
project= ABC AND "Epic Link"= 'Epic1' AND status != 'closed' AND issuefunction in linkedIssuesOf(" "Epic Link" = Epic1 ")
```

but it doesn't seem to understand this `issueFunction in` or `issue in`

Can someone please help me out

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following-

project = ABC  AND "Epic Link" = Epic1 and issue in childIssuesOf("Epic1")